# Changing my code to keep certain columns instead of delete columns

Tags: excel, vba

I've frankensteined some code together which does the following:

- Deletes first few rows in a worksheet if they're not the header names
- Deletes columns with specific names
- Does this for all worksheets in a specified folder

I need help updating the code to do the following:

- If the first row already contains the headers, then it will just move to the next step
- Keeps columns with specific names, delete the rest
- Do this for all sheets within a worksheet, if there happen to be multiple ones

Thank you so much in advance for any help!

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook

    MyPath = "C:\Users\Katerina Shapiro\Desktop\VBA" 'Change this based on your folder path'
    
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    
   
    MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.xlsx")
    
    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    
        If MyFile <> wkb.Name Then
    
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyPath & MyFile
            
            Dim rng As Range

            Set rng = Range("B1:B4") 'Change this if there are more rows to be deleted before the header'
            rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
        
            
            Dim xFNum, xFFNum, xCount As Integer
            Dim xStr As String
            Dim xArrName As Variant
            Dim MR, xRg As Range
            On Error Resume Next
            Set MR = Range("A1:H1")
            xArrName = Array("Placement (detail) url", "Placement (group)") 'enclose each column name with double quotes and separate them by comma
            xCount = MR.Count
            xStr = xArrName(xFNum)
            For xFFNum = xCount To 1 Step -1
            Set xRg = Cells(1, xFFNum)
            For xFNum = 0 To UBound(xArrName)
            xStr = xArrName(xFNum)
            If xRg.Value = xStr Then xRg.EntireColumn.Delete
            Next xFNum
            Next
            
            ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
            
        End If
            
        MyFile = Dir
        
    Loop
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Completed...", vbInformation

    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Should get you close:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim wkb As Workbook, wbMod As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyFile As String, h, keepCols, col As Long, i As Long
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook 'ThisWorkbook ?

    MyPath = "C:\Users\Katerina Shapiro\Desktop\VBA" 'Change this based on your folder path'
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    
    keepCols = Array("Placement (detail) url", "Placement (group)") 'columns to keep
    
    MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.xlsx")
    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
        If MyFile <> wkb.Name Then
            
            Set wbMod = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyPath & MyFile) 'get reference to opened file
            For Each ws In wbMod.Worksheets 'loop over worksheets
            
                'remove any empty rows at the top of the sheet
                i = 0
                Do While Application.CountA(ws.Rows(1)) = 0
                    ws.Rows(1).Delete
                    i = i + 1
                    If i >= 5 Then Exit Do 'don't keep deleting forever...
                Loop
                'loop column headers in Row 1 right to left: delete column if header not in "keep" array
                For col = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column To 1 Step -1
                    If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Cells(1, col).Value, keepCols, 0)) Then
                        ws.Columns(col).Delete
                    End If
                Next col
            
            Next ws
            wbMod.Close True 'save changes
        End If
        MyFile = Dir()
    Loop
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Completed...", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For i = 1 To 2 'This for loop deletes all rows on top of the workbook where the cell in column B is empty
If Cells(i, 2).Value = "" Then
Rows(i).Delete
i = i - 1
End If
Next
```

This one should solve your first problem.

```
WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
For i = 1 To WS_Count
...
Next i
```

If you implement this loop it looks how many sheets there are in the workbook and loop through it.

```
For i=1 to Cells(7, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If Cells(1,i).Value="" Then 'You need to insertthe Names of the columns you want to keep here.
        columns(i).delete
        i=i-1
    endif
Next
```

And this should solve the columns delete problem.